# Python Docx: How to Set Column Width as "Autofit to contents"

Tags: python, pandas, docx, python-docx

I used this code:

```
# open a document
doc = docx.Document()

# add a table to the end and create a reference variable
# extra row is so we can add the header row
t = doc.add_table(df.shape[0]+1, df.shape[1])
t.allow_autofit = True
t.style = 'TableGrid'
t.alignment=WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
```

Where `df` is some `pandas` `DataFrame`. But the columns are not auto-fitting.

[image]

Comment: "Either algorithm will adjust column widths proportionately when total table width exceeds page width." Could it be the case that you are exceeding the page's width?

Comment: I don't think so, this is a table with values of 3 digits...

Comment: @Zev: I've added the screenshot. This is Word 2013 do you happen to have a different version?

Comment: I was thinking that you were saying the columns were too small rather than too large so I misunderstood. I get what you are looking for now and am trying a fix.